# When is a logarithm equal to a whole number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logarithms

Are there any conditions a logarithm must meet to be a whole number?

In other words: $x=\log_y(z)$, when will $x$ be a whole number?

Comment: $y^x=z$ and $y$ must be multiplied a whole number of times to produce $z$.

Comment: This is equivalent to $z=y^x$.

Answer (score 1):

Your comments make clear that what you want is a method for deciding whether $x=\log_y z$ is a whole number, without calculating the logarithm.

It suffices to decide if $z$ is an integer power of $y$. To learn this:

- Let $z'=z$, and repeatedly divide $z'$ by $y$ until either:

  - $z'=1$. The answer is yes, $x$ is an integer
  - $z'$ is not an integer. The answer is no, $x$ is not an integer

For example, is $x=\log_8 1521364$ an integer? Divide $1521364$ by $8$ repeatedly: $1521364\div 8= 190170\frac12$ is not an integer, so $x$ is not either.

But $2097152\stackrel{\div 8}{\to} 262144\stackrel{\div 8}{\to} 32768\stackrel{\div 8}{\to} 4096\stackrel{\div 8}{\to} 512\stackrel{\div 8}{\to} 64 \stackrel{\div 8}{\to} 8\stackrel{\div 8}{\to}1$, so $\log_8 2097152$ is an integer.

Alternatively, you can run the algorithm backward, computing $y, y^2, y^3, \dots$ until you find an $i$ for which $y^i≥z$. Then $\log_y z$ is an integer if and only if $y^i=z$. A version of this method that computes $i$ with binary search will be faster if $z$ is very large.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(t):=\log_y(t)$ for $t>0$. Then

$f((0, \infty))= \mathbb R$.

Hence for each $x \in \mathbb Z$, there is $z \in (0, \infty)$ with $x=\log_y(z)$

Comment: Okay, but I don't really see how this answers my question. I want to know if there is a way for me to tell if a certain logarithm is a whole number or not. We know that $\log_3(9)$ gives us a whole number, namely 2, and that $\log_3(12)$ doesn't end up as an integer, but how can I tell this without mechanical calculations? For example $\log_8(1521364)$, is there a way I can tell if this gives me an integer or not without calculating it?